# How to change date format using a class?

Tags: php, date

I want to change the date format in a text box where the date format is d-m-y I used the class **w8em format-d-m-y highlight-days-67 range-low-today** is it possible if I change it into **w8em format-m-d-y highlight-days-67 range-low-today** to change the **d-m-y** to **m-d-y**

here's is my form.

```
Start Date: <input type="readonly" class="w8em format-d-m-y highlight-days-67 range-low-today" name="start" id="sd" value="" maxlength="10" required=""<br>
End Date:<input type="readonly" class="w8em format-d-m-y highlight-days-67 range-low-today" name="end" id="ed" value="" maxlength="10" required=""<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById( "sd" ).className = "w8em format-m-d-y highlight-days-67 range-low-today";
```

Comment: then i could use the class w8em format-m-d-y highlight-days-67 range-low-today?